# XBMC, libGL error: failed to load driver: i915

Tags: drivers, 14.10, xbmc

I am a brand new Linux user, and while installing XBMC I received this code in the terminal:

```
libGL error: Version 4 or later of flush extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: i915
Running DIL (3.22.0) Version
DtsDeviceOpen: Opening HW in mode 0
DtsDeviceOpen: Create File Failed
libGL error: Version 4 or later of flush extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: i915
libGL error: Version 4 or later of flush extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: i915
```

XBMC runs, but I am worried that the video drivers are not installed properly, and I am at a bit of a loss as to where to begin.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be due to not supported DRI3 by intel 915 driver. Update to mesa 12.0. See this bug at: https://issues.openmandriva.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1439